# Angular 2 - Multiple templates

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So i have an application where i need to be able to load different templates at runtime.

My standard template looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Template 1</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>


</body>
</html>
```

Now at one point i would like to change to the following template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Template 2</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/reveal.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/theme/black.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/reveal.js-3.6.0/lib/css/zenburn.css">

</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>

<script type="application/javascript" src="assets/reveal.js-3.6.0/lib/js/classList.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="assets/reveal.js-3.6.0/lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="assets/reveal.js-3.6.0/js/reveal.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is how can i do that? Either using `components` or `modules`?

Comment: What's your condition to change the template? Can't you directly serve the right one from your webserver if it's for 2 separate applications?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good practice to dynamically change the content of index.html, From what I can see, you only need to load few css and js files, when certain conditions are met.

Instead of touching the content of index file, how about handling what resources need to be loaded (and load them) inside a separate service while your application is being initialized?

It may look a little bit hacky, but it worked for me, at least for loading some additional css.

**app.module.ts**

```
export function ResourceProviderFactory( provider: ResourcesService ) {
  return () => provider.loadResources();
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ResourcesService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: ResourceProviderFactory,
      deps: [ ResourcesService ],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**resources.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class ResourcesService {

  private _resources = {
    typeA: [
        'assets/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/reveal.css'
        'assets/reveal.js-3.6.0/lib/js/classList.js'
    ]
  }


  constructor( private _http: HttpClient  ) {
  }

  public loadResources(): Promise<boolean> {
    let res;
    if( condition_met ) {
        for( let r of this._resources.typeA ) {
            res = this._resources.typeA[r];
            if( res.indexOf('css') >= 0 ) {
                loadCSS( res );
            }else if ( res.indexOf('js') >= 0 ) {
                loadJS( res );
            }
        }
    }
  }

  public loadCSS( resourcePath: string ) {
    const link = document.createElement( 'link' );
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = 'resourcePath;
    document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0].appendChild( link );
  }

  public loadJS( resourcePath: string ) {
    const link = document.createElement( 'link' );
    link.type = 'application/javascript';
    link.href =  resourcePath;
    document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0].appendChild( link );
  }

}
```

Comment: The reason i wish to change the content of the index file is because it is basically two applications in one

Answer (score 0):

You could divide your application in one main and multiple sub-layouts.

The application to land on the main layout-component and then load sub-layout on condition having its own styles (you can import additional CSS in sub-component's own css file)..

**main-lauoyt.component.html:** (The application lands here)

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**sub-layout-1.component.html** (all layout type 1 components land here)

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**sub-layout-1.component.css**

```
@import 'path to assets/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/reveal.css';
@import 'path to assets/reveal.js-3.6.0/css/theme/black.css';
@import 'path to assets/reveal.js-3.6.0/lib/css/zenburn.css';
```

(Do the above for type 2 layout component and import the other bunch of css files there)

**Set your paths like this:**

```
{path: 'type1', component: layoutType1Component,
children: ["all the child component paths of type-1 layout"],},
{path: 'type2', component: layoutType2Component,
children: ["all the child component paths of type-2 layout"],},
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="lessons" [ngIfElse]="loading">
   <div class="lessons-list">
     ... 
   </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #loading>
    <div>Loading...</div>`enter code here`
</ng-template>
```